# Cocoa: NSView origin x at the bottom

Tags: cocoa

I am programmatically creating a `NSWindow` and the controls on it.

It seems the origin (0,0) is at the lower left corner. This is strange to me (coming from other GUI toolkits). Is there some flag or so so that I can change this so that the origin is in the left top corner?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On OS X the origin is at the lower left corner. That's true for screen coordinates and view frames. You can override [`isFlipped:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsview_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/isFlipped) in an NSView subclass and return YES to make the upper left corner the origin of that view, but I don't think there is a way to do the same for screen coordinates.

Comment: Well, yea, that is what I also have researched so far. But isn't there an easier way? Also, does everyone who want to do this always have to reinvent such `NSFlippedView` class which is just an `NSView` with `isFlipped` returning `YES`?

Comment: I think in most cases the easiest solution is to just reverse your math. It's annoying if you come from iOS programming, but it's not that hard.

Comment: In the [Cocoa docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Transforms/Transforms.html), it says: "If you plan to draw all of your view’s content using flipped coordinates, overriding the view’s isFlipped method is by far the preferred option."

Comment: If you're planning to do that, sure. I was just saying if you're starting something from scratch (not a port of an iOS app) then why not simply do the math with the lower left corner being the origin?

Comment: Because when constructing the window, I usually have a list of controls which I construct from top to bottom.

Comment: The only thing you have to change is not starting at `y=0`, but `y=self.frame.size.height` and not adding the controls' heights but subtracting.

Comment: That already seems more complicated and counter-intuitive (as I am going top to bottom). Also, I'm not sure but I guess it wouldn't work when resizing? Of course, intuitive would be that the position of my controls wont change if I resize the window.

Comment: Yes, it's unintuitive and annoying. Resizing will work if you got your autoresize masks (or constraints) right.

Comment: But I don't think there are any more options. Either subclass and flip your view or reverse the math :-/